# how to handle steam/condensation from baseboard steam radiator

Tags: baseboard, radiator, condensation, steam

The baseboard steam radiator we had installed in 2016 as part of a kitchen renovation often causes water to pool on the (hardwood) floor because steam/condensation from the outlet doesn't seem to have anywhere to go (see attached photo). What's the best way to avoid having water end up on the floor?[image: baseboard radiator steam outlet]